# Hierarchial SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion, hierarchy

I have a self-referencing table (Customers) and a table that will link to one record in that table (Companies) i.e.

```
Customers      Companies
*********      *********
ID             ID
ManagerID  --> DirectorID
```

ManagerID refers to another record in the Customer table.

I need to perform a query where by given a specific customer ID, it will find the Company that customer belongs to. If I was to do this in C# it would look something like (this is sample code, not functional):

```
public static Company FindCompany(Customer customer)
{
     while (customer.ManagerID != null)
     {
          customer = customer.GetManager();
     }
     return Company.FindByDirector(customer.ID);
}
```

So there are 2 steps:

1) Traverse up the Customer table (via ManagerID) until we find a Customer with no ManagerID. (The Director)

2) Find the Company relating to that Customer.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, untested though.

Based on CTEs [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(SQL.90).aspx)

```
WITH cTE AS
(
    SELECT --Get manager of given customer
        ManagerID
    FROM
        Customers
    WHERE
        ID = @MyCustomerID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT --Get manager of the manager etc
        Customers.ManagerID
    FROM
        cTE
        JOIN
        Customers ON cTE.ManagerID = Customers.ID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cTE
    JOIN
    Company ON cTE.ManagerID = Company.DirectorID
```

Comment: +1 - CTEs are the way to go in SQL Server 2005 onwards for building hierarchies

Comment: I tweaked this a little and got it to work thanks. Is this query possible using LINQ?